# Adding licenses to 3rd party license in Settings Android app

Tags: android, android-source, licensing

I'm working on an Android 11 project and we need the ability to add our licenses to Android from the Android source code.

This list is located in the **Settings** app: `About tablet > Legal information > Third-party licenses`, where an HTML view displays all third-party licenses.

How can we add licenses so that they can be displayed here?

I've done some research but I'm mostly finding plugins to find the licenses on your app or how to display them inside your app, but nothing about how to get these licenses in the Settings app and display them on the view of the Third-party license.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you creating a custom build of Android to serve as custom firmware?

Comment: @CommonsWare yes, we are creating a custom image, so the idea is to include it from the source code into the Settings app

Comment: Presumably, using `grep` or your favorite text search tool, you can search the source code of the Settings app that you are including in your firmware, and from there you can figure out how to add new licenses.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering, I got help internally at my job.
To achieve this in Android **11** there is a mechanism that will look for any license file named **NOTICE** in any directory with an Android.mk and/or Android.bp file defining the module. The content of the NOTICE file must be the third-party license.

After compiling, this will display the license in the Third-party license view of the Settings app.

> Apparently for Android 12 a similar approach is needed but it requires more steps.